# Imagemagick to merge and mask images

Tags: merge, imagemagick, mask, imagick

I recently started working with Imagemagick and I had a problem that needs to be solved.

I have such a thumbnail.

[image: thumbnail]

And there is such a mask.

[image: cloud-mask]

I need to get this image on the output.

[image: complete]

I looked through this link http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/ I tried everything there, but I did not get success ((

I hope you will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a result very much like your example...

```
convert mask.png image.png -gravity north -composite \
      mask.png -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

You can adjust the positioning of the overlay by including something like "-geometry -10+0" before the first composite.

To use this command in Windows you'll need to change that continued line backslash "\" to a caret "^".

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, you should extract the alpha channel of your mask and put that into the alpha channel of your other image. So try

(unix syntax)

```
convert KlQZ6.png \( 7k9a9.png -alpha extract \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

(windows syntax)

```
convert KlQZ6.png ( 7k9a9.png -alpha extract ) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]